# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when posting data from form to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing a simple input field and submit the data from the form to controller but always get the MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="sale/api">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Subdomain Name
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="api_key" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Api Key
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="api_key" class="form-control" id="api_key" name="api_key">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Controller

```
    public function sync()
    {

        $input = Input::only('name','api_key');            
        $user = new Sale;
        $user->name = $input['name'];
        $user->api_key = $input['api_key'];

        Debugbar::info($user->name);
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::post('sale/api','SaleController@sync');
```

Comment: add "@csrf" token in your from.

Comment: `action="sale/api"` is a relative URL and is just an invitation for issues. Do `action={{ action("SaleController@sync") }}` to get the correct URL based on your routes.

Comment: I always use the `route`-helper to generate paths that are always right

Comment: @apokryfos same error, I'm not sure which part was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your route.php as,

```
Route::post('/sale/api',array('as' => 'sale.api', 'uses' => 'SaleController@sync'));
```

Update your blade as,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('sale.api')}}">
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: new error, `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was laravel 4. now update route please.

Answer (score 0):

It is your action that needs amending:

**html:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('sale.api') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
            Subdomain Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="api_key" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
            Api Key
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="api_key" class="form-control" id="api_key" name="api_key">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**route:**

```
Route::post('/sale/api','SaleController@sync')->name(sale.api);
```

hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add csrf field in your form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="sale/api">            
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Laravel won' let you post without the csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

update the form like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('sale/api')}}">
```